# Facebook App, login and stream.publish with PHP not working

Tags: php, facebook

I created and application in facebook (it's in "sandbox mode").
I added a "connect to facebook" button in a page.
The login works OK, but when I try to use the method stream_publish, I get that error :

```
Uncaught exception 'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action' in
```

I noticed that when I log in, it doesn't say "Publish content to your Wall" in the login popup. I see that when I log in on digg.com with the facebook connect button, but I don't see that in my app.

So do I need to set some kind of settings in my application settings... Is there another of login a user that will grant my application to post data on his stream?

**Update #1**

This is the line I use to edit my stream :

**$this->facebook_connect->client->stream_publish($message,null,null,XXXXXX,XXXXXXXX);**
Where XXXXXXX is my user id on FB.

**Update #2**
When I log in my profile on FB, go to "Account", "Application Settings", "Edit settings" on my application, I don't see the "Publish content to my Wall" as in the "Events" application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abra kadabra

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'req_perms' => 'publish_stream'
        )
);
```

Source : http://thinkdiff.net/?p=1767

Comment: looks like a great tutorial. I'll take a look at this one too! Thanks a lot! I was using the REST api, I guess it's outdated...

Comment: To remove the "iframe" type of app, just remove the "canvas" parameter.. It works great, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to have the publish_stream permission in order to publish to the stream. I know that sounded obvious, but in order to get this permission, and other extended permissions, you have to specifically request them. I don't know exactly how to do this with PHP, but these links might help:

[Extended Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions)

[Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) (see the section "Requesting Extended Permissions")

[PHP SDK Tutorial](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/phpsdk/learning_phpsdk_06.html)

Comment: yea I saw that "publish stream" permission somewhere. it's just that the facebook API DOC is SO clear (sarcasm). Thanks, I'll take a look at those pages!